# Error in SQL Server local temporary table

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am working on SQL Server 2014 and getting this error message

```
msg 208, level 16, state 0, line 8  
Invalid object name '#LocalTemporaryTable'.
```

can anybody explain me why I am getting this error message.
you can see the image below what i have tried.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to refresh your intellisense and then try again.

It works for me

[image]

Comment: It's error from execution. Refreshing intellisense doesn't help.

Comment: @qxg:- Then may be OP has to select all the text and the press F5 as lad2025 said. It is working for me on my system.

Comment: @JasonClark:- Did you check that the table is not dropped or the table exists? As it is working fine for me.

Comment: @JasonClark:- At the top of your page where you are writing the query include this line and execute it `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LocalTemporaryTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #LocalTemporaryTable`

Answer (score 0):

From screenshoot you provided it seems to me that you are trying to execute only `INSERT` statement.

Solution:

- First you need to create table. Highlight `CREATE TABLE ...` and press <kbd>F5</kbd>.
- Or just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd>